# Objective C calling method from another call

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, ios7, azure-mobile-services

I have created a class AuthService

in AuthService declaration I have this

```
- (MSClient *) getClient;
```

and in the implementation (.m file) I have this

```
- (MSClient *) getClient{
    client =[MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"XXXXXXX/"
                                      applicationKey:@"XXXXXXX"];
    return client;
}
```

Now I'm tring to get the instance of the MSClient in a view controller during a button click as below.

AuthSerivce class is initialised like this in .h file first

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AuthService *authService;
```

client is declared as MSClient object and sythesized as below

```
@synthesize client;
```

Then I tried to create  a client object from the AuthService class (yeap I refered AuthService.h in the view controller)

```
client = [authService getClient];
```

But my problem is that, getClient is always returning `nil`

I'm sure I'm missing something in basic objective c OOP conceps. Please correct me.

Comment: How you are initializing authService ??

Comment: @MidhunMP hey I already have the `getClient` method above

Comment: @MrjComics: my mistake, Please post `clientWithApplicationURLString` method.

Comment: ` @property (strong, nonatomic) AuthService *authService;` initialised like this

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks. `clientWithApplicationURLString` is a framework method from Azure sdk.

Comment: In addition to the answer from rdelmar below, since you wrote your own version of `getClient`, you don't need to `@synthesize` one either.

Comment: authService is empty (nil Pointer). You need to initialise authService. `@property (strong, nonatomic) AuthService *authService;` is not initialisation; its declaration. You need to initialise like this `authService = [[AuthService alloc] init];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a property does not initialize it. So this line,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AuthService *authService;
```

doesn't create an instance of AuthService, you need to alloc init one before you can call getClient.

Comment: Thanks that makes the sense. As I suspected missed some fundamental OOP stuff.

Answer (score 1):

you  might need to call this in your view did load

```
authService = [[AuthService alloc]init];
```

this might do.

Comment: Thanks your answer is clear and precise, but @rdlmar already answered. Will accept his answer. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

authService is empty (nil Pointer). You need to initialise authService. 
`@property (strong, nonatomic) AuthService *authService` is not initialisation; its declaration.

You need to initialise like this authService = [[AuthService alloc] init];

Sending a message to a nil object, in your case `[authService getClient]`, will return nil always.
Basics of Objective-C. :P